# iphonesimulator (SDK not found) error in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

I've been trying to resolve this issue for a while now. The reason I am trying to build for a simulator is to get screenshot on a retina 4 inch display which is now required in the appstore. I am making an app with unity and i see from the forums that people are successful in making simulator builds.

When making regular build for iphone/ipad I dont have any errors, but opening my project (in unity it is marked as simulator) and trying to build it to simulator fails with linker errors (see below). It's obvious that `"iphonesimulator (SDK not found)" message in Architecture -> Base SDK selection list`. Although when checking to preferences -> downloads, all simulators are installed. I am able to manually start a simulator

I am beginner to iphone/ipad development, especially in Xcode and I was searching through the forums about this problem and did not find anything that would resolve my problem. Can anybody point me in the right direction? What should I try and where should I look out for errors?

Thank you!

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/mirko/Dropbox/Unity'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LProjects/Project3D'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LProject/Project3D/Builds/iOS/S3D"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/mirko/Dropbox/Unity'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LProjects/Project3D'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LProject/Project3D/Builds/iOS/S3D/Libraries"'
0  0x10a87b098  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10a87e431  mach_o::relocatable::Section<x86>::addRelocFixup(mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>&, macho_relocation_info<Pointer32<LittleEndian> > const*) + 1781
2  0x10a88e636  mach_o::relocatable::Section<x86>::makeFixups(mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>&, mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::CFI_CU_InfoArrays const&) + 90
3  0x10a88aaad  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 1433
4  0x10a8820c3  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 313
5  0x10a87faa1  mach_o::relocatable::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 149
6  0x10a8a033a  archive::File<x86>::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File<x86>::Entry const*) const + 794
7  0x10a89fb50  archive::File<x86>::forEachAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 198
8  0x10a8b176c  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) + 420
9  0x10a8ba884  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 44
10  0x10a87b380  main + 370
11  0x10a86ccd4  start + 52
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/Project3DSystem-2013-02-20-134511.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (src.atom != NULL), function addRelocFixup, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-136/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 5468.
```

Comment: any progress on that?

Comment: Which version of Unity and Xcode are you using? Some don't work with others.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in my project but I'm not using Unity3D. I've find some material related to this:

> Yes,I had met this problem at my frist time to run a game on
>   simulator. At last I found the SDK version must be the same .if you
>   selected 4.1 in unity3d, then you must run it on 4.1 version
>   simulator.  Does it give you any helps?

Original link:[iphonesimulator (SDK not found)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/161985-iphonesimulator-%28SDK-not-found%29)

Answer (score 0):

Check you deployment target and set it to 4.3 or higher. Also see Objective C/C++ compiler and set it Apple LLVm Compiler 5.0 (xcode 5) .

After this check you base SDK in build settings and change make sure it is set iOS Latest 7.0 or whatever latest SDk you have.

You have to check deployment target both in target and project icon in prject settings pane.

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling xcode unless you already did that.